# When was the last defeat by filibuster of a government-backed bill in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, filibuster

Let's define defeat as the bill not passing that [session](https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/occasions/calendar/).

Wikipedia [lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filibuster#United_Kingdom) a number of successful filibusters but most (if not all in that list) appear to be on private bills or advanced by a minority party. Wikipedia lists one *unsuccessful* attempt to filibuster (in the House of Lords) the government-backed Parliamentary Voting System and Constituencies Act 2011.

So when was the last time that a *government-backed* bill was defeated by filibuster in the UK?

Comment: It'd be long ago,  probably 1800s. I'm sure it would be pre-Parliament act.

Comment: On the other hand, delaying in the Lords is relatively common.  The lords can delay and the unpredictable nature of the timing of elections means that it fairly common that a bill doesn't pass all its stages.  When was the last time parliament was prorogued?  There was probably unfinished business then.  I'm sure that at the controversial brexit proroguing of parliament there were some government bills that had to be re-introduced

Comment: @JamesK The last prorogation must have been just ahead of this year's [State Opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_State_Opening_of_Parliament) in May.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tentative answer, as there are usually at least a few Government bills that don't make it through Parliament each session. In the most recent session (21-22), for example, the Online Safety Bill, the High Speed Rail (Crewe - Manchester) Bill, and the Animal Welfare (Kept Animals) Bill ran out of Parliamentary time. None of these ran out of time due to a concerted filibustering attempt though, and all were carried over to the current session.

The last instance that I can think of of a Government bill being dropped due to a filibustering effort was the Parliament (No. 2) Bill back in 1969. The bill was introduced to implement the recommendations of a somewhat controversial White Paper on House of Lords reform, which would have created a system of voting and non-voting Lords, reduced the number of Lords Spiritual, altered some of the Parliament Acts' provisions to reduce the maximum length of time the Lords could delay a bill to six months, and so on.

The bill had its second reading [on February 3rd](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1969-02-03/debates/acb7b261-9cbd-4355-90ca-ae4074795a12/Parliament(No2)Bill), and was referred to a Committee of the Whole House. The opposition promptly set about a large filibustering effort, and by April 17th, 10 full days of parliamentary time had been spent debating the bill, covering just the preamble and five of its twenty clauses. At this point, the government gave up - and Harold Wilson [announced to the Commons](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1969-04-17/debates/acf37c61-eb8b-40b1-997a-ef155be1c76a/Parliament(No2)Bill) that the bill would no longer be pursued.

> Following the Government's decision to introduce early legislation for
> the purpose of giving statutory effect to some of the salient
> proposals in the White Paper "In Place of Strife", Cmnd. No. 3888, it
> is now clear that the legislative priorities governing the
> Parliamentary timetable for the rest of this Session must be recast in
> order to give right of way to the Industrial Relations Bill, and—as
> soon as this can be made ready—the Merchant Shipping Bill, which my
> right hon. Friend the Leader of the House recently indicated that the
> Government wished to bring forward this Session.
>
> The Government have, therefore, decided not to proceed further at this
> time with the Parliament (No. 2) Bill in order to ensure that the
> necessary Parliamentary time is available for priority Government
> legislation, including the two Measures to which I have just referred.
>
> My right hon. Friend the Leader of the House will, at the appropriate
> time, keep the House informed about the Government's further
> intentions on the matter of the Bill.

Comment: To do the obvious math, 54 years ago.